# How does Gradle's java plugin run JUnit tests in parallel: one queue per fork or a single queue and multiple forks?

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, queue, junit4

I have been recently trying Gradle, I didn't have any prior experience with it, and so far I have been able to do the things I wanted to and am satisfied with the results. However, in my case I have to run Selenium tests with JUnit and some of them are disproportionately larger than others (i.e.: 25min vs 4min).

When using the `maxParallelForks` option, sometimes it takes longer than I would expect, as the tests seem to be assigned beforehand to the forks and sometimes I end up with iddle forks, while one of them is stuck with a long test, and when it finishes other shorter tests run after it (which could have run in any of the other available forks).

**TL;DR:**
When running tests in parallel, Gradle seems to assign tests as if there were multiple queues (one per fork) and I would like it to be like a single queue where the forks take the next test in the queue.

**As an off-topic example, my situation is like being stuck in a queue at the supermarket, when the ones next to you are empty, but you can't change.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the latter. gradle uses one queue and distributes each entry clockwise to the running processes. Say you have 4 tests:

- Test1 taking 10s
- Test2 taking 1s
- Test3 taking 10s
- Test4 taking 1s

and using `maxParallelForks = 2` the overall test task execution would be around 20s. I guess we need to discuss if this can be improved by getting notified about "free" processes to assign Test3 directly to test worker process 2 after Test2 comes back after 1s.

Comment: This solves my doubts, I will take this into account when running tests in parallel; and it's great to get info from a Gradle team member directly.
Also, considering what you mention at the end, it would be nice to have something like that in a future version, for situtations like this; but that's up to you (the team) to decide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2021, Your question (and my experience) matches the issue described in [this issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3955) which
"has been automatically closed due to inactivity".

The issue is not resolved, and yes, the system assigns tasks early and does not rebalance to use idle workers.